# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused with Laravel 9.x + docker

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel 9.x and XAMPP. The `php artisan migrate`.
command works great. When I use `postman` to implement the register function, it returns this error:

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL:
            SELECT count(*) AS aggregate FROM `users`
            WHERE `email` = quangthin2000@gmail.com)",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
```

[image: Error image]

My .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testproject
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Is your database populated and does the user *quangthin2000@gmail.com* exists?

Comment: No, this is the first record

Comment: Ok so you will need to populate your database first with a dump and/or create manually your user via the MySQL cli.

Comment: I have created manually my user. After that, I use ```login function``` . It has error similar when I use register function by postman.

Comment: Please show your code for the login function/register function

Answer (score 1):

The error is Connection Refused, your application is failing to even connect to the SQL server in the first place. There may not even be a problem with your business logic because you're failing before you even get to that point. Make sure your database is actually running and accessible on the host and port you specified.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your .env file

```
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```